# IIS6 Manager from remote machine not showing ASP.Net Configuration

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-6

I am accessing IIS6 Manager of Windows Server 2003 remotely from my Windows 7 machine using IIS6 manager console, but the ASP.NET version dropdown neither showing any version nor I can edit the configuration of website. However on server itself it shows all versions of ASP.NET and I can edit configuration of website.

[image]

Have anyone experienced this before? Am I missing something?

Thanks :)